# How to get error line/column number from SQL syntax error or executing exception from libpq?

Tags: postgresql, error-handling, libpq

When I execute a SQL command via `libpq`, it reports error message if there's some error something like this.

```
Error Domain=PQConnection Code=1 "ERROR:  syntax error at or near "fef"
LINE 1: fef
        ^
```

This is string message. I can parse the message - because it's very regular - to get line/column number, but that's unreliable. Is there any other API to get line/column numbers? Any regularized integer form would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

Use `PQresultErrorField` function with key `PG_DIAG_STATEMENT_POSITION`.

From [manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/libpq-exec.html)

> PG_DIAG_STATEMENT_POSITION A string containing a decimal integer
>   indicating an error cursor position as an index into the original
>   statement string. The first character has index 1, and positions are
>   measured in characters not bytes.